# rake :db migrate does not return anything

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

i created a model Article and addedd the following code in 001_create_articles.rb

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
create_table :articles do |t|
    t.string :title
    t.text   :body
    t.string :published_at

    t.timestamps
end
  end
def self.down
drop_table :articles
end
end
```

Then i tried running

```
 rake db:migrate --trace
```

I dint get any output, the console just blinks for a minute.
The output of the rake is

```
C:\InstantRails-2.0-win\rails_apps\blog>rake db:migrate --trace
(in C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/rails_apps/blog)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

also **rake :db migrate is not working in anyof my projects**

Also Mysql server is running and i am able to login to the server. my database.yml file is fine.

Is this a configuration issue or i am missing something?

Comment: Are you sure this migration has not already been done? Usually the migration files are prefixed by a timestamp. What have you got in your schema_migrations table in your database?

Comment: @Aditya. In my rails (2.0.2) only numbers are prefixed. There is a file schema.rb which does not hav articles table detais. Its crazy. It was working till yest. But now all of a sudden it is not :( and, its a new scaffolded application

Comment: Did you generate your migration using ruby script/generate migration or just created the migration file by hand?

Comment: when i created the scaffolded application it was there by default. i did no create by using ruby script/generate

Answer (score 1):

Your database has a schema_migrations

if the file has already been run the version number will be there, you can remove the entries in that DB and run db:migrate, note that it will probably remove all your data as well.

if you want to make an incremental change to the db without modifying the data you can create a new migration that modifies the existing database structure an example:

```
note that you need to do this in a new migration file.
class AddAttachmentCxpp1ToCustomer < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :customers, :cxpp1_file_name, :string
    add_column :customers, :cxpp1_content_type, :string
    add_column :customers, :cxpp1_file_size, :integer
    add_column :customers, :cxpp1_updated_at, :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :customers, :cxpp1_file_name
    remove_column :customers, :cxpp1_content_type
    remove_column :customers, :cxpp1_file_size
    remove_column :customers, :cxpp1_updated_at
  end
end
```